# Have to tap 2 times in a button to have a result

Tags: android, file-io, button

public void calcul ()
{
      final EditText vol;
      final EditText kil;
      final EditText cons;
      context = getApplicationContext();
      vol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volume2);
      kil= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kilometrage2);
      cons= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.consom2);

```
 final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

 String value1 = vol.getText().toString();
 String value2 = kil.getText().toString();


                     if (value1 != null && /*value1.trim().length() > 0 &&*/ value2 != null /*&& value2.trim().length() > 0*/)
                     {
                             float q1=Float.parseFloat(vol.getText().toString());
                             float q2=Float.parseFloat(kil.getText().toString());
                             float x=((q1 / q2)* 100);
                             String y= Float.toString(x);
                             cons.setText(y);

                             SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
                              String date = format.format(new Date());
                              data = date + " : " + y + "L/100KM"+ " " + value1 + "L "+ value2 + "KM\n";
       SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      if (data != "" ) {
      String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
      String fileDir = ""+ preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
      myIO.WriteSettings(context, fileDir + fileName, data);
      data = "";

      Toast.makeText(carburant.this, "Donnée ajoutée!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                     }
                     else 
                     {
                     Toast.makeText(carburant.this, "Veuillez vérifier les deux champs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
     }
```

});

WriteSettings method:

```
public class myIO {
public static void WriteSettings(Context context, String nom, String data) {
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

    try {
        fOut = context.openFileOutput(nom, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        fOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        try {
            osw.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you flushing the write out to the file ?

Comment: Yes, i'll just add the WriteSettings method in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

How is the snippet of code being called?  What are value1/value2?  If this is the on click event, it's possible that value1 or value2 are null values on the first click, preventing any settings from being changed.

Comment: I think it is inside of an onClick event for a listener because he has }); at the bottom, but he left out the top part.

Comment: @DMags, @Tim: i edited my first post with whole function! Thank you for trying helping me :).

Comment: You're welcome :) Are you sure that you should be using the toString() function after GetText() for value1/value2? I believe that's for getting the class name, not for converting to a string type (Though I could be wrong, if the function is overloaded).  Also, what are the values of vol and kil?